# How I can catch an event that appears in the system(android)?

Tags: java, android, mobile

**Hello,**

I am developing an application (android 2.35), and part of the development I need to know about a specific event that took place in the system, such as clicking on the "Manage Applications" or press on "Settings".
I can do so? how?
If someone has a code about this, I appreciate it.

Thank for helpers,

Comment: Actually, I would like to send email when someone try to remove\remove my application, So I thought by tracking the event I will know when my application is removed..  I saw a solution through, brodcast PACKAGE_REMOVED but it does not work when my application is removed.  semone have a creative solution for me??

Answer (score 0):

you can catch a `keyEvent` and Events which sends `Broadcaste`... i don't think catching user activity is possible in android..

Comment: Actually, I would like to send email when someone try to remove\remove my application.